# element1+element2 - Selects all element1 elements that are placed immediately after element2 elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS previous sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector)

This css selector selects all element1 elements that are placed immediately after element2 elements

```
element1+element2 {

}
```

Is there any selector that would select all element1 elements that are placed immediately **before** element2 elements?